# How to interact with tezos running in a docker

Tags: docker

I just set up a local enviroment according to
https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html using the babylonnet.sh

I am not familiar with docker but I could make sure with "docker stats" that everything seems to run fine.

[image: my just set up docker env]

But I now struggle with the further documentation.
The system does not know for example the

```
tezos-node
```

command.
I just get a

```
iMac:Downloads user$ tezos-node
-bash: tezos-node: command not found
```

How do I interact with tezos that run within a docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All interaction with the dockerized `tezos-node` (should) go through the
`./babylonnet.sh`, `alphanet.sh` or `mainnet.sh` script (the name of
the script depends on which network your node is connecting to.)
Typically, you do not interact with `tezos-node` directly, and indeed,
the script has few commands related to the node. Excerpt from
`./babylonnet.sh --help`:

```
./babylonnet.sh node <start|stop|status|log>
./babylonnet.sh node upgrade
./babylonnet.sh restart
```

instead, you communicate with the node (and through the node, with the
network), by using the `tezos-client`. The dockerized `tezos-client`
is also accessed through the `./babylonnet.sh` script:

```
./babylonnet.sh client <COMMAND>
   Pass a command to the tezos client.
```

To see the manual of the tezos-client (also [available online](https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/cli-commands.html#client-manual)), try the following:

```
./babylonnet.sh client man
```